# Changing IP address with user configuration in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ip

Can I somehow make my IP address appear different when I log for Example in Facebook? I don't mean something like proxy server or VPN rather something similar to changing User Agent in Network Conditions in Chrome.

Comment: User agent and IP are different topics. Which one do you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

No. There's a large difference between how these two parameters are used.

The User-Agent field is purely informative; the web server doesn't need it at all to do its job. The IP address, on the other hand, is required for data routing/delivery – without it, the response from Facebook cannot reach your computer.

So although you *can* change your router's IP address to something else, the reply packets will actually *go* to that fake location instead of you, and your browser won't be able to establish any connection at all.